# Calling a function inside document.ready, jquery

Tags: jquery, function, execute, document-ready

i have a code like this

```
<script>$(document).ready(function(){

        var myPlayList = []; 

        //document.write(whatTo);
        //New instance of jPlayerSkin
        var skin = new jPlayerSkin( '#jplayer_container' , myPlayList );

        //Start the player
        skin.initialize();
 });

</script>
```

and i have function , which is `function updatePlaylist(song,title,url) { /* code */ }`

Now all i want is to execute this updatePlaylist function in document.ready because in this function i also call skin.add() , which is available in document.ready only. But when i place the function in document.ready() , i can't execute it, and if i put it outside, i can execute the function but it can't access skin.add().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move `var myPlayList = [];` and `var skin = null` outside of the document.ready, try again with `updatePlaylist(song,title,url)`in document.ready

Comment: then you have a syntax error, post all the code including updatePlaylist, or send link to it

Comment: The method you told worked like a charm :) i was having a syntax error over there :) Thanks allot!!

Answer (score 0):

Don't put the function inside the function you pass to `document.ready`, that will just locally scope it.

Keep it as a global and just call it from that function.

Comment: i cannot even global it there!!